# Loading Song in MonoGame Windows

Tags: xna, c#, monogame

I cannot load the song into my game. I got error in both templates WindowsDX and WindowsGL. Monogame Develop Build 1252

Both files .wma and .xnb are exist in Content folder and Build Actions are sets to Content, and Copy Always to output dir. Checked with mp3/ogg too but with no result.

The Song works perfect with XNA, and with MonoGame I cannot load any song.

Edit SOLVED: The newest build 1478 solved the problem

DX
[image: windowsDX]

GL
[image]

Comment: The newest build 1478 solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, You may be pointing to the wrong directory, file, or type of file.

Make sure to Add the song to game content by Right-Clicking on your designated Content Folder >> Existing File >> Select the File.

Make sure that your audio is supported by the Content Pipeline : http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/managing-content.

Verify that the File Name is the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem(or feature?) of Monogame where you have to specify the file type for audio because both files are generated in the Content Builder.
I believe it is .ogg for music and .wav for SFX. You can check the file types in the built content folder(default: Content).